# Disallowing proxies from POSTing

Tags: php, web-applications, proxy, spam-prevention

I want to disallow proxies and spambots from posting in my website. What is the best way to do so?

I've downloaded a blacklist and my first idea was to disable each of ips in my .htaccess file, but after downloading [the list](http://cbl.abuseat.org/), I found out that it contained almost 9 million entries.

My other idea was to split each IP in 4 parts and do [1;4] successive SQL queries in my POST.

Yet if I could cache this values on memory, I could inexpensively check for them with something like (:200 (:188 (:10 (:42)))). Is this doable with PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've presented the problem in other way, assuming that maintaining such structure was possible, and I've got some other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545826/is-there-a-way-to-maintain-a-200mb-immutable-data-structure-in-memory-and-access).

I'll create a RAMDISK with loads of inodes to represent the mentioned tree, and hopefully it will work.